# Why java circular generic spec does not allow to cast "this" into generic instance

Tags: java, generics, subclass

I can make a circular generic class dependency, but somehow I can not cast (without compile error) "this" instance into generic reference. As far as I know - it is impossible to create subclasses which break dependency in circular generic scenario.

```
public class P
{
    public static abstract class Network<C extends Client<N, C>, N extends Network<C, N>>
    {
        private C client;

        public void addClient(C client)
        {
            this.client = client;
        }
    }

    public static abstract class Client<N extends Network<C, N>, C extends Client<N, C>>
    {
        private N network;

        public void setNetwork(N network)
        {
            this.network = network;
        }

        public void attachOtherClient(C client)
        {
            network.addClient(client);
        }

        public void attachSelf()
        {
            attachOtherClient(this); //does not compile, but it is impossible to create subclasses that breaks this safety (i think)
        }
    }

    public static class TCP extends Network<MK, TCP>
    {

    }

    public static class MK extends Client<TCP, MK>
    {
        @Override
        public void attachSelf()
        {
            attachOtherClient(this); //compiles without problems
        }
    }

}
```

I apologize for my bad English.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C` extends `Client<N,C>`, but `Client<N,C>` (the type of `this`) does not necessarily extend `C` (the parameter type of `attachOtherClient()`).

> but it is impossible to create subclasses that breaks this safety

Not impossible. Consider

```
class TCP extends Network<MK, TCP> { }
class MK extends Client<TCP, MK> { }
class MK2 extends Client<TCP, MK> { }
```

This satisfies all the bounds and compiles properly. Yet inside `MK2`, if you pass `this` to `attachOtherClient()`, you will be passing a `MK2` to something that expects `MK`, which is obviously wrong.

Comment: I understand. But is it possible to model circular generics which allow only 2-class dependency? I mean - MK2 subclass of Client<TCP,MK> should be impossible to compile.

Comment: @MichaelP: 2-class dependency is not relevant. The same thing happens with 1-class "self-bounded" types -- it is impossible to have a type parameter such that `this` is guaranteed to be an instance of the type parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You should use more generic classes:

```
public static abstract class Network<C extends Client<N, C>, N extends Network<C, N>>
{
    private Client<N, C> client; // <== generic type

    public void addClient(Client<N, C> client)
    {
        this.client = client;
    }
}

public static abstract class Client<N extends Network<C, N>, C extends Client<N, C>>
{
    private Network<C, N> network; // <== generic type

    public void setNetwork(N network)
    {
        this.network = network;
    }

    public void attachOtherClient(Client<N, C> client)
    {
        network.addClient(client);
    }

    public void attachSelf()
    {
        attachOtherClient(this); //  compiles & works: 'this' has type Client<N, C>, not C
    }
}
```